# Multiple properties with name 'BadgeView.Shared.CircleView.CornerRadius' found - Exception

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, titleview

I am using [**`BadgeView`**](https://github.com/SuavePirate/BadgeView) plugin in Xamarin.Forms with `TitleView` but getting exception

> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 8:81. Multiple
>   properties with name 'BadgeView.Shared.CircleView.CornerRadius' found.

This is my code

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="End" Spacing="10">
    <Image Source="bell.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"></Image>
    <badge:BadgeView Text="2" BadgeColor="Yellow" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Start"></badge:BadgeView>
    </StackLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the plugin which is marked in the issues section in the plugin's [Github](https://github.com/SuavePirate/BadgeView/issues/11)

And there is a workaround that one guy has added but I am not sure if that would work for you, as shown [here](https://github.com/SuavePirate/BadgeView/issues/11#issuecomment-437788180) what he did was

**CircleView.cs**

Note: Comment the CornerRadius property.

```
    public class CircleView : BoxView
{
    //public static readonly BindableProperty CornerRadiusProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CornerRadius), typeof(double), typeof(CircleView), 0.0);
    //public double CornerRadius
    //{
    //    get { return (double)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty); }
    //    set { SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value); }
    //}
}
```

**For Android:**

**CircleViewRenderer.cs**

Note: Added hard-coded value for CornerRadius (16)

```
public class CircleViewRenderer : BoxRenderer
{
    private float _cornerRadius;
    private RectF _bounds;
    private Path _path;
    public CircleViewRenderer(Context context)
       : base(context)
    {
    }
    public static void Initialize() { }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<BoxView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Element == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        var element = (CircleView)Element;

        _cornerRadius = TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, (float)16, Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics);

    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        if (w != oldw && h != oldh)
        {
            _bounds = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
        }

        _path = new Path();
        _path.Reset();
        _path.AddRoundRect(_bounds, _cornerRadius, _cornerRadius, Path.Direction.Cw);
        _path.Close();
    }

    public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.Save();
        canvas.ClipPath(_path);
        base.Draw(canvas);
        canvas.Restore();
    }
}
```

For iOS:
CircleViewRenderer.cs
Note: Added hard-coded value for CornerRadius (16)
iOS code is not tested yet.

```
public class CircleViewRenderer : BoxRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<BoxView> e)
   {
       base.OnElementChanged(e);

       if (Element == null)
           return;

       Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
       //Layer.CornerRadius = (float)((CircleView)Element).CornerRadius / 2.0f;
       Layer.CornerRadius = (float)(16) / 2.0f;
   }
}
```